# Installing pandas with tox for py26

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6, python-2.6, tox

There is an issue when using `tox` to run `pytest` for my package using py26 as one of the envs (global env is py3.6, py26 env is py2.6.9 installed via `pyenv`)

tox.ini file:

```
[tox]
envlist = py26,py27,py36
[testenv]
deps=
   pytest
   PyPDT
   py26: numpy<1.12.0
   py{27,36}: numpy
   py26: pandas==0.16.2
   py{27,36}: pandas
   py26: matplotlib<1.5.0
   py{27,36}: matplotlib<2.1.0

commands=pytest
```

The following error occurs during `pandas` installation:

```
Collecting pandas==0.16.2
  Using cached pandas-0.16.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/pr/ghw8lmr94c5g9ntx4cp9990w0000gn/T/pip-build-cuCAyE/pandas/setup.py", line 406, in <module>
        from wheel.bdist_wheel import bdist_wheel
      File "/Users/brianpollack/Coding/scikit-hep/.tox/py26/lib/python2.6/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 407
        ignore=lambda x, y: {'PKG-INFO', 'requires.txt', 'SOURCES.txt',
                                       ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/pr/ghw8lmr94c5g9ntx4cp9990w0000gn/T/pip-build-cuCAyE/pandas/

ERROR: could not install deps [setuptools, pytest, PyPDT, numpy<1.12.0, pandas==0.16.2, matplotlib<1.5.0]; v = InvocationError('/Users/brianpollack/Coding/scikit-hep/.tox/py26/bin/pip install setuptools pytest PyPDT numpy<1.12.0 pandas==0.16.2 matplotlib<1.5.0 (see /Users/brianpollack/Coding/scikit-hep/.tox/py26/log/py26-1.log)', 1)
```

Any idea what's causing this syntax error?

EDIT:

Updated best answer: using `-cconstraints.txt` to enforce downgraded version of `wheel`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wheel` [dropped support for Python 2.6](https://github.com/pypa/wheel/commit/c9e54864b64ad5c949bfb6ce8cdfd77df03647ef).

To install `wheel` compatible with Python 2.6 install version [0.29](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel/0.29.0):

```
source /Users/brianpollack/Coding/scikit-hep/.tox/py26/bin/activate‌​
pip uninstall wheel
pip install wheel==0.29.0
```

In tox.ini:

```
[testenv]
deps=
    …
    py26: wheel==0.29.0
    …
```

Or try [constraints file](https://tox.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example/basic.html#depending-on-requirements-txt-or-defining-constraints):

```
[testenv]
deps=
    …
    -cconstraints.txt
    …
```

constraints.txt:

```
wheel==0.29.0
```

Comment: Thanks, that does look the source of the problem.  However, even when requiring a downgraded version of wheel, the same error appears.  Do you have a prescription that requires pip to use that wheel version for the subsequent packages?

Comment: Remove `/Users/brianpollack/Coding/scikit-hep/.tox/py26` directory and rerun `tox` with updated `tox.ini`.

Comment: Yeah I removed that and reran, and also removed all the cached wheels of the various dependencies.  I am still running into this error.  I'm using tox v2.9.1

Comment: `source /Users/brianpollack/Coding/scikit-hep/.tox/py26/bin/activate`; `pip uninstall wheel`; `pip install wheel==0.29.0`

Comment: Excellent, this prescription works and the rest of the packages can then be installed manually as well.  Unfortunately, running `tox -e py26` after explicitly installing wheel==0.29.0 reinstalls wheel==0.30.0.  Is it possible to prevent tox from reinstalling wheel?  If not, I will open a gh issue.

Comment: Try constraints file. I extended the answer.

Comment: I'm trying and the constraints file is ignored... help @phd?